# FMDB Result set contains null iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, fmdb

I am using FMDB for my application to store data in sqlite. Here is my code

from AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

{

FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/sql.sqlite"];

```
if (![db open]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not open db.");

}
NSLog(@"DB opened successfully");
```

// full code not shown here

}

I have following code in  ViewController

```
-(IBAction)insertButtonClicked:(id)sender
```

{
    NSLog(@"in insertButtonCLicked");

```
[db beginTransaction];

[db executeUpdate:@"insert into sample (url) values (?)",@"google'"];

[db commit];
```

}

-(IBAction)displayButtonClicked:(id)sender

{

```
NSLog(@"in DisplayCLicked");

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select url from sample"];

NSLog(@"Rs contains => %@",rs);

while( [rs next])
{

    NSLog(@"%@",[rs stringForColumn:@"url"]);
}
[rs close];
```

}

When i run this code i get rs as null as shown in following (this is o/p from console)

```
2011-03-07 07:30:06.919 InsertDataSample[3092:20b] DB opened successfully
```

2011-03-07 07:30:13.341 InsertDataSample[3092:20b] in insertButtonCLicked

2011-03-07 07:30:16.860 InsertDataSample[3092:20b] in DisplayCLicked

2011-03-07 07:30:16.860 InsertDataSample[3092:20b] Rs contains => (null)

Plz help me friends. I am working on FMDB from many days but i am unable to use FMDB .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert this just after your query and FMDB will probably tell you exactly what the problem is.

```
if ([db hadError]) {
    NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
}
```

**Update:**

Running this:

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/sql.sqlite"];
[db executeUpdate:@"create table sample (url TEXT);"];
[db executeUpdate:@"insert into sample (url) values(?);", @"google'"];
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select url from sample;"];
while ([rs next]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [rs stringForColumn:@"url"]);
}
[rs close];
[db close];
```

produced this output:

```
2011-03-06 12:38:59.831 test[93163:207] google'
```

Comment: Thnkas for reply. But still there is same problem i.e Result set contains NULL . Is it necessary to create table programatically in FMDB? Bcoz I created sample.sqlite using terminal & written only create query & added that file in my resources alongwith libsqlite3.0.dylib.

Comment: But did the log output show a DB Error once the new code was added?  And yes it is necessary to create the 'sample' table before attempting to insert rows.  (You can also add the error log output after executeUpdate.)

Comment: There are no errors even after adding new code. I created table in viewDidLoad method. Still same problem , record set is null